# How to insert into database using PDO where columns to insert change?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've got a scenario where I'm needing to enter data into a database; however I don't always have the same data to enter into the database.

The values I have are all stored into an array.

There is also another value in a separate variable which also needs to be inserted.

Here's what I have so far, however I'm unsure if this is the best way to be doing it as it seems rather crude.

```
$cols = "Id, ";
$vars = ":Id, ";
$start = "INSERT INTO table (";
$mid = ") VALUES (";
$end = ")";
    foreach($array as $key => $val){
        $cols .= ", " . $key;
        $vars .= ", :" . $key;
    }
    // Probs a better way to do this?
}
$stm = $this->db->prepare($start . $cols . $mid . $vars . $end);
//Now I use this statement to enter variables into DB
```

Just to clarify what sort of data I'm expecting to help explain what I'm trying to do. Imagine I have a table that lists the number of fruit a particular vendor sold each day. So the columns would be apples, bananas, oranges, strawberries.

Now a vendor may only sell one type of fruit, in which case I'll only have data for that type of fruit. However a vendor may also sell two different types of fruit, they may also sell 0 of the fruit they sell.

So I'll have data in the form of:

- Vendor 1, apples: 0, oranges: 2
- Vendor 2, apples: 1, strawberries: 3
- Vendor 3, apples: 5, bananas: 4

Which I need to insert into the same table.

Comment: Please keep in mind [an SQL injection against which prepared statements won't help](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/sql_injection_example)

Comment: @YourCommonSense I figured as much; which is why I was trying to figure out if there was a different way to do this. I still want to use PDO as the statement will be used a few times with the same columns (they just change on different sets of data). But am open to all ideas at the moment.

Comment: @sherif : why was your answer deleted

Comment: is it only insert statement that you are going to use ?

Comment: @Laith Yes it's only insert statements. There are 20 or so columns in the table, but I don't always want to insert data in all of them.

Comment: so you want your code to be in PDO only ? or anything else ?

Comment: @Laith I would prefer PDO; but I'll use whatever is cleaner. I'll generally reuse the same statement for about 10 inserts before I need to regenerate the statement for a new set. Everything else is PDO so I was just keeping it consistent.

Comment: another Q , im still trying to understand what you need sorry , are the fields always the sane , i mean ( id) field ? if you could explain just one more time what you need exactly . Thank you

Comment: @Laith you can read the link I posted above, it explains it pretty much clear

Comment: @Laith Updated the question with an illustration of what I'm trying to achieve; however just with a lot more columns.

Comment: You mean SQL injection link ?

Comment: @Laith yes, I posted only this one so far

Comment: @Rawrskyes for your case you need different database structure. Sold goods have to be stored in rows, not columns. this way you'll be able to add new goods easy way. If this sketch explains your task then the solution is quite simple

Comment: @YourCommonSense good suggestion , i agree with you . And as for me i was lost in his Q lol , i know about SQL injection , when i said " another Q " that Q was directed to him :) and he explain his Q , but im still lost lol , maybe my english is the  issues or knowledge issue for me .

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'm not sure I understand what you mean by that? You mean to generalise the column into 'goods sold' rather than the type of fruit?

Comment: You have to use an additional table to store the goods sold this day. consists of the order id, good id and quantity. While goods themselves have to be stored in a third table. This is how relational databases work

Comment: Since you're already down the road of writing an ORM, have you tried any of the existing ones? [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) and [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent) are all good choices if not examples to work from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's no other alternative solution that I was able to find here. However I would like to mention that as per a comment on this question; you need to be wary of SQL injection when you're allowing columns to be dynamically selected like this.

An article [here](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/sql_injection_example) explains quite nicely what needs to be done to protect against SQL injection.

Answer (score -3):

You may try this

```
$array = array('id'=>1, 'name'=>'harry', 'age'=>14);

$cols_array = array();
$vals_array = array();

foreach($array as $key => $val){
    $cols_array[] = "'".$key."'";
    $vals_array[] = "'".$val."'";
}

$cols_string    =   implode(",",$cols_array);
$vals_string    =   implode(",",$vals_array);

$insQry = sprintf(" INSERT INTO table (%s)
                    VALUES (%s)
                    ",
                    $cols_string, 
                    $vals_string);
echo $insQry;
```

Comment: They should never try this

Comment: That looks almost identical to what I already have; just in a more roundabout way.

Comment: @Rawrskyes it is not identical but much worse as it doesn't utilize prepared statements at all

Comment: @Your Common Sense : Noted.